# How to translate Oracle PLSQLAssociativeArray in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, npgsql

I have a task to convert this method from oracle to postgres.

The method contains a parameter as such:

```
            NpgsqlParameter myParam= new NpgsqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "Myvalues",
                NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Varchar,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Collection = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
                Size = 2,
                Value = myList.ToArray(),
                ArrayBindSize = myList.Select(_ => _.ToString().Length).ToArray()
            };
```

What is the best way to translate this over? Collection = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray, and ArrayBindSize are not applicable to this NpgsqlParameter.

Is there a way to pass in array as a single param??

Comment: Associative array semantically is same to dictionary. You could to use [typed row](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html), [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) or [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) for this, depending on how you want to use it in PostgreSQL itself.

Comment: thanks for you message, can you provide a code example of how this work work in the param? i cannot find anything to support

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has not associative arrays. You can use 1D or 2D arrays instead.

Comment: could you provide example for explanation? apologies engilsh is not first languiage